# Replace undefined with 0s in array of objects without double for-loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let zed = [
    { name: 'tom', stat1: undefined, stat2: 3 },
    { name: 'nic', stat1: undefined, stat2: undefined },
    { name: 'joe', stat1: 5, stat2: undefined },
]

zed.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
        array[index][key] = array[index][key] === undefined ? 0 : array[index][key];
    });
});
```

The code above works but we are concerned about performance on much larger arrays of objects in our react application. Also not sure if mutating the array inside of a `forEach()` is considered a bad practice in React, perhaps it is better to create a new array somehow with `.map()`. Any recommendations on the best way to replace `undefined` with `0`?

Comment: Depends on what `zed` comes from and how often you see yourself performing this step to replace with 0s

Comment: If all objects have the same set of keys, then you can move the `Object.keys(value)` outside of the `forEach`.

Comment: This runs each time the page on our app using this function re-renders. If the function becomes very costly we can wrap it in a `useMemo()` to avoid it being called on every render. Regardless, we want a decently performant way to remove the `undefined`s

Comment: You're always going to have to touch every value of every object, so the complexity is set.

Comment: Not sure you have much to worry about performance no matter how you do this, but you could simplify with -> `zed.map(m => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(m).map(([k,v])=>[k, v === undefined ? 0 : v])))`  And this will not mutate either,..

Comment: @Keith mutation is undoubtedly more performant than creating that many intermediate objects. Terseness does not equate with performance.

Comment: @pilchard  Like the OP mentions, mutation is often a bad word in React.. :), and he asked -> `create a new array somehow with .map()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not without a double loop, but there is still room for optimisation:

You could:

- Avoid the `forEach` callback by using `for..of` syntax
- Use `value` instead of `array[index]`
- Use the `??=` assignment operator (which will also replace `null`)

```
for (const value of zed) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(value)) {
        value[key] ??= 0;
    }
}
```

If you are sure that the objects in `zed` have no other enumerable keys other than **own** keys, you can use `in`:

```
for (const value of zed) {
    for (const key in value) {
        value[key] ??= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! `for...of` with `for...in` is the fastest one.

Answer (score 2):

If we trust the [`JSON.stringfy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) built-in function to work efficiently, then the following solution is sure to be very efficient

```js
let zed = [
    { name: 'tom', stat1: undefined, stat2: 3 },
    { name: 'nic', stat1: undefined, stat2: undefined },
    { name: 'joe', stat1: 5, stat2: undefined },
]

    let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(zed, (k, v) => v === undefined ? 0 : v))

    
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: A replacer is possibly good, but depends on the shape of the rest of the data. (any methods lost?).

Comment: It was by mistake of course, I immediately edited my answer :)

Comment: Might it be that simple looping through an object is faster than stringifying, _then_ reparsing?

Comment: It's very, very hard for me to believe this, conversion to a string works in a fraction of a second even on very large objects

Comment: Interesting idea, I can give it a try and compare performance. off hand I don't know if looping is faster than stringifying and reparsing. I do worry about types potentially being changed with this approahc.

Comment: Can you share what cases you fear? And of course I would love to hear the results of your test, I will also check the speed right now

Comment: I tried my solution on `500,000 objects` in an array and it took `206.97998046875 ms`, Very fast in my opinion

Comment: Did you compare it to the original example?

Comment: Actually no, I'll compare now

Answer (score 2):

Seen as performance is mentioned a fair bit here,

Just knocked up a quick benchmark showing a few examples from here,..

In all cases, there all pretty fast, but the fastest seems to be `for in` atm.

The slowest as expected is map, but this is a none mutation version..

On my machine.

```
foreach: 12.200ms
map: 36.200ms
json: 32.500ms
key_in: 5.500ms
obj_keys: 9.400ms
```

```js
let _zed = [
    { name: 'tom', stat1: undefined, stat2: 3 },
    { name: 'nic', stat1: undefined, stat2: undefined },
    { name: 'joe', stat1: 5, stat2: undefined },
]

function makeBigZed() {
  const r = [];
  for (let l = 0; l < 50000; l += 1) {
    r.push(_zed[l % 3]);
  }
  return r;
}


let zed = makeBigZed();
console.time('foreach');
zed.forEach((value, index, array) => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
        array[index][key] = array[index][key] === undefined ? 0 : array[index][key];
    });
});
console.timeEnd('foreach');

zed = makeBigZed();
console.time('map');
let r = zed.map(m => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(m).map(([k,v])=>[k, v === undefined ? 0 : v])));
console.timeEnd('map');


zed = makeBigZed();
console.time('json');
r = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(
  zed,
  function(k, v) { return v === undefined ? 0 : v; }
));
console.timeEnd('json');


zed = makeBigZed();
console.time('key_in');
for (const value of zed) {
    for (const key in value) {
        value[key] ??= 0;
    }
}
console.timeEnd('key_in');


zed = makeBigZed();
console.time('obj_keys');
for (const value of zed) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(value)) {
        value[key] ??= 0;
    }
}
console.timeEnd('obj_keys');

zed = makeBigZed();
console.time('pil');
const result = []; for (const v of zed) { const t = {}; for (const k of Object.keys(v)) { t[k] = v[k] ?? 0; }; result.push(t); }
console.timeEnd('pil');
```

Comment: The performance gains inherent in using `for...of` and `for...in` can still be utilized and avoid mutation. The big hit in the `map` example is the creation of all the intermediate objects.

Comment: `const result = []; for (const v of zed) { const t = {}; for (const k of Object.keys(v)) { t[k] = v[k] ?? 0; } }`

Comment: @pilchard I've added yours to the list, I assume you meant to put the `result.push(t)` so I've added that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```js
let zed = [
    { name: 'tom', stat1: undefined, stat2: 3 },
    { name: 'nic', stat1: undefined, stat2: undefined },
    { name: 'joe', stat1: 5, stat2: undefined }
];
for(let k_arr in zed){
    for(let k_obj in zed[k_arr]){
        if(zed[k_arr][k_obj] === undefined){
            zed[k_arr][k_obj] = 0;
        }
    }
}
console.log(zed);
```

Comment: "Without a double for-loop."

Answer (score 0):

**Lodash**, if you don't mind. In fact, an average result.

```js
const zed = [
    { name: 'tom', stat1: undefined, stat2: 3 },
    { name: 'nic', stat1: undefined, stat2: undefined },
    { name: 'joe', stat1: 5, stat2: undefined },
];

const result = _(zed).forEach(o => _.transform(o, (r, v, k) => r[k] ??= 0, o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```